# EF- How to do a 'Not In' using Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq-to-entities

I'm using the Entity framework 3.5 and am having trouble running this query.

I have the following entities: Applicant, application, and applicationstatusHistory (tracking job applicants)

I'm looking for matches in **Application** where there are no matching ***applicationids*** in **applicationstatusHistory** with an id of -insert param here-. The 2 entities are joined by applicationid.

Here's my current statement:

```
 applications = context.Application.Include("Applicant").Include("ApplicationStatusHistory")
                        .Where(LinqExtension.BuildContainsExpression<Application, int>(a => a.Id, applicationIds))
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: What trouble are you having with the query? Is there a particular error you are receiving?

Comment: No, this is just the partial. It doesn't contain the logic to not include where application.applicationid = applicationstatushistory.applicationid and applicationstatushistoryid = 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's going ion in the BuildContainsExpression, but here's a WhereNotIn method that I found somewhere that I've been using:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereNotIn<T, TValue>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, TValue>> propertySelector,
    IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    if (propertySelector == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("propertySelector");
    }

    if (values == null || !values.Any())
    {
        return query.Where(i => true);
    }

    var param = propertySelector.Parameters.Single();
    var unequals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.NotEqual(propertySelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
    var body = unequals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, unequal) => Expression.And(accumulate, unequal));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);

    return query.Where(lambda);
}
```

Edit: As noted in the comments, this code needs to be placed in a static class to be used as an extension method.

Comment: Cool! Could you post an example of the call for us noobs? Thanks!

Comment: Current recommendation would be to upgrade to EF4, which supports Contains() directly.  Call would be something like: applications = context.Application.Include("Applicant").Include("ApplicationStatusHistory").Where(a => a.Id, applicationIds)).ToList();

Comment: @radus var listToExclude = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; var results = db.Table.WhereNotExists(x=>x.IntColumnName, listToExclude);  This assumes you have the code listed in a static class so it can execute as an extension method :-)